# Adding file path to listbox item

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, listbox

I'm trying to store the file path in a tag of a listbox item.

I'm using the below to search through and add the desired folder name to the list box

I've added the `ListBox1.Tag = sDir` line to above the first `Next` and when I step thorugh the code the value of `sDir` appears to hold the path however if I create a simple `Double click` event that pops up a message box with the file path in it only shows the first folder name in the list.

Any tips or advice - I basically want to select a Listbox item and have it point to its path!

Thanks

```
 For Each Dir As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("c:\Working")

        Dim dirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Dir)

        For Each sDir As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(dirInfo.ToString)

            Dim sdirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(sDir)

            ListBox1.Items.Add(sdirInfo.Name)
            ListBox1.Tag = sDir
        Next

    Next
```

Comment: there is only one tag for all the items in the ListBox so if the items can have different paths that wont work.  You can store objects as items, so you could write a simple class to store the filename, path and whatever else as each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store objects as items, so a small class to store item info:

```
Public Class myClass
    Public Property FileName as String
    Public Property PathName As String
    Public Foo As Integer

    ' class is invalid w/o file and path:
    Public Sub New(fName As String, pName As String)
         FileName = FName
         PathName = pName
    End Sub


    ' this will cause the filename to show in the listbox
    Public Overrides Function ToString() AS String
         Return FileName
    End Sub
 End Class
```

You can now store these in the listbox as you load/find them:

```
 Dim El as MyClass           ' temp var for posting to listbox

 ' in the loop:
 El = New MyClass(filename, pathName)    ' use names from your Dir/File objects
 ListBox1.Items.Add(El)
```

and to get it back:

```
 ' INDEX_TO_READ is a dummy var of the index you want to get
 ' SelectedItem will also work
 thisFile = Ctype(ListBox1.Items(INDEX_TO_READ), MyClass).FileName
 thisPath = Ctype(ListBox1.Items(INDEX_TO_READ), MyClass).PathName
 ' or:
 Dim aFile As myClass = Ctype(ListBox1.Items(INDEX_TO_READ), MyClass)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help -really appreciate it. Am i missing something really straightforward as i'm getting El, filename, pathname & INDEX_TO_READ as `is not declared` errors

Comment: The code above is more like snippets for how to use them *generally* rather than finished code - I couldnt see where the file name was coming from.  INDEX_TO_READ is a dummy variable where you use the index of the list item you are after (or use SelectedItem or SelectedIndex - the point was supposed to show how to cast an item back to a myClass object). See the edit.