# add a table of Structures to a listbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox

i have a structure in a module that i instanciate a table of its type

```
Public Structure Client
    Public _nom As String
    Public _prenom As String
    Public _age As Integer
End Structure

Module Module1
    Public TableauClient(0) As Client
End Module
```

that i need to populate nd resize every time i hit a certain button

```
Dim Dimension As Integer = 0

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
            TableauClient(Dimension)._nom = TextBox1.Text.ToString()
            TableauClient(Dimension)._prenom = TextBox2.Text.ToString()
            TableauClient(Dimension)._age = Val(TextBox3.Text)
            Dimension += 1
            ReDim TableauClient(Dimension)
End Sub
```

the problem is i need to fill a listbox with all the elements in the table when i hit another button but i don't even know where to start to do this, tried datasource or add item by item by using concatenations between the three fields but still couldn't get it right

Comment: The smart way you be to use a Class instead of a structure, and a List instead of an array.  There are examples of this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23679571/1070452), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23205262/1070452) and [also here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25449991/1070452).

Answer (score 0):

you can still use the structure but, I think it will be easier to work with class.  Instead of Array make a list

```
dim TableauClient as new List(of Client)
```

create toString inside your class / structure

```
Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
   return _nom 
End Function
```

and just add those into your listbox

```
listbox.items.add(TableauClient (0))
```